# Multiple foreign key constraints to distinct subsets of same relation

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys

I have some *x*s. Every *x* either is or is not a *y*:

1. *y* ∪ *not_y* = *x*
2. *y* ∩ *not_y* = ∅

A *y* is a special *x* that can point to many other *not_y*s. A *not_y* cannot point to any *x*.

Is there a way to create a relation *z(y, not_y)* such that *(y, not_y)* is unique and the above constraints are enforced?

*x* and *y* could be modeled as two tables with a foreign key constraint, for instance:

```sql
create table x(a integer not null, primary key (a));
create table y(
    a integer not null,
    primary key (a),
    foreign key (a) references x (a)
);
```

*y* could also merely be a property of *x*. I have a lot of freedom in defining the model.

The naive take of

```sql
create table z(
    y_a integer not null,
    not_y_a integer not null,
    primary key (y_a, not_y_a),
    foreign key (y_a) references y (a),
    foreign key (not_y_a) references x (a)
);
```

prevents duplicates and enforces the integrity of *y<sub>a</sub>* (provided *y* retains integrity but we can afford that assumption) but doesn't enforce the second constraint. I could make a moral opposite of the *y* table:

```sql
create table not_y(
    a integer not null,
    primary key (a),
    foreign key (a) references x (a)
);
```

Then use that for the `not_y_a` foreign key constraint, extending the same assumptions to the `not_y` table as to the `y` table. However, then I have double-bookkeeping of *y*-ness, which I suspect is more costly to me than tolerating the limitations of the `z` table.

Another way to think of it is to say that I'm looking for a negative foreign key constraint.

[SQL Fiddle for consideration](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/99be3/6).

I'm using PostgreSQL 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE x (
   id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
   is_y boolean NOT NULL,
   UNIQUE (id, is_y)
);

CREATE VIEW y AS
SELECT id FROM x WHERE is_y;

CREATE VIEW not_y AS
SELECT id FROM x WHERE NOT is_y;

CREATE TABLE z (
   y_id bigint NOT NULL,
   y_is_y boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE
      CHECK (y_is_y),
   not_y_id bigint NOT NULL,
   not_y_is_y boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
      CHECK (NOT not_y_is_y),
   PRIMARY KEY (y_id, not_y_id),
   FOREIGN KEY (y_id, y_is_y) REFERENCES x (id, is_y),
   FOREIGN KEY (not_y_id, not_y_is_y) REFERENCES x (id, is_y
);
```

This requires an explanation:

- `x`, `y` and `not_y` really are the same table. `is_y` determines if a row belongs to `y` or to `not_y`. The partition is automatically disjoint, and it is covering because `is_y` is not NULL.
- The unique constraint on `x` is needed as a target for foreign keys.
- The two `boolean` columns in `z` are implementation artifacts and are always constant. They are needed for the foreign keys, so that a `y_id` is guaranteed to point to a `y`.
- Uniqueness of the mapping in `z` is guaranteed by the primary key.

Comment: This struck me as the more pragmatic solution. Working SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/86948/5

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do:

```
create table x (
    x_id int not null primary key,
    y_id int unique
);

create table y (
    x_id not null primary key
    constraint fk_y_x_id foreign key (x_id) references y(x_id)
);

alter table x add constraint fk_x_y foreign key (y_id) references y(y_id);
```

The two unique constraints would seem to do what you want.  However, it is a little tricky to insert data into the above data model.

You might also want to look into table inheritance.  It might be a more direct way to do what you want.